# Primitive that occupies 8 bits in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I was surprised to discover, when using [Spacetime](https://github.com/lpw25/prof_spacetime) to profile my OCaml, that my `char` and even `bool` arrays used a word to represent each element. That's 8 bytes on my 64 bit machine, and causes way too much memory to be used.

I've substituted `char array` with `Bytes` where possible, but I also have `char list` and dynamic arrays (`char BatDynArray`). Is there some primitive or general method that I can use across all of these vector data structures and get an underlying 8 bit representation?

Comment: Have you looked at the stdlib's `Bigarray` (or helper modules on top of it, like `Bigstring`, `Bigstringaf`, `Ctypes`, etc.)? Like `Bytes` it can be structured with `char`, but it can also represent multi-dimensional arrays efficiently.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your quesiton the first time and wrote a somewhat off-topic answer: I’ve edited now. The short answer is: use `Buffer` from the standard library. Or perhaps `Bigarray` as @VPhantom said.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks @VPhantom. Bigarray seems to be the way to go. It looks like it supports packed versions of 8, 16 and 32 bit integers. It doesn't grow on demand, but - that's not a big deal - I'll just implement a dynamic array using Bigarray as a building block.

Answer (score 4):

*Edit: I read your question too fast: it’s possible you already know that; sorry! Here is a more targeted answer.*

I think the general advice for storing a varying numbers of chars of varying number (i.e. when doing IO) is to use buffers, possibly resizable. [Module `Buffer`](https://ocaml.org/api/Buffer.html) implements a resizable character buffer, which is better than both `char list` (bad design, except for very short lists perhaps) and `char BatDynArray` (whose genericity incurs a memory penalty here, as you noticed).

---

*Below is the original answer.*

That’s due to the **uniform representation of values**. Whatever their type , every OCaml value is a machine word: either an *immediate value* (anything that can fit a 31- or 63-bit integer, so `int`, `char`, `bool`, etc.), or a pointer to a *block*, i.e. a sequence of machine words (a C-fashion array), prefixed with a header. When the value is a pointer to a block we say that it is “boxed”.

Cells of OCaml `array`s are always machine words.

In OCaml, like in C++ but without the ad-hoc overloading, we just define specializations of `array` in the few cases where we actually want to save space. In your case:

- instead of `char array` use `string` (immutable) or `bytes` (mutable) or `Buffer.t` (<del>mutable</del> appendable and resizable); these types signal to the GC that their cells are never pointers, so they can pack arbitrary binary data;
- Unfortunately, the standard library has no specialization for `bool array`, but we can implement one (e.g. using `bytes`); you can find one in several third-party libraries, for instance [module `CCBV`](http://c-cube.github.io/ocaml-containers/last/containers-data/CCBV/index.html) (“bitvectors”) in [package `containers-data`](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/containers-data/).

Finally, you may not have realized it, but `float`s are boxed! That’s because they require 64 bits (IEEE 754 double-precision), which is more than the 31 or even 63 bits that are available for immediates. Fortunately(?), the compiler and runtime have some adhoc-ery to avoid boxing them as much as possible. In particular `float array` is specially optimized, so that it stores the raw floating-point numbers instead of pointers to them.

---

Some more background: we can distinguish between pointers and immediates just by testing one bit. Uniform representation is highly valuable for:

- implementing garbage collection,
- free parametric polymorphism (no code duplication, by contrast with what you’d get in a template language such as C++).

Comment: Thanks! A lot of useful insights in your answer. The issue with using `Buffer`, which I tried, is that you cannot set characters in it, at least not efficiently. So there's no equivalent of `Bytes.set` to my knowledge.

Comment: Oh! You’re right, `Buffer`’s API is append-only. That’s a surprise to me. Quick look at [the code](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/buffer.ml): the implementation is a mere wrapper around `bytes`, reallocated on need, and I can’t see how exposing `Buffer.{get,set}` would cause any problem… PR perhaps?